# What kind of space return me a faithfully and transitively group action on a set?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, homogeneous-spaces

> a homogeneous space for a group G is a non-empty manifold or topological space X on which G acts transitively

But I try understand What kind of space I get if I add also [faithfully](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaithfulGroupAction.html) condition not only a transitive (group) action.

Example:  I know that an affine space is a group action on a set, specifically a vector space acting on a set faithfully and transitively, so I search for a name for this algebraic structure *between* affine space and vector space. Exist a name or a way to build algebraically this space?

For vector space I look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369932/g-fin-ab-group-acts-faithfully-transitively-on-x-then-x-g)

And I find also something [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680282/definition-of-an-affine-space/2680355#2680355)

> All depends the point of view you like (at that is a matter of taste),  IMHO, the "most connected" (with the rest of mathematics) is that of *an orbit* under translations. Then you have (a) a group of translations $(T_v)_{v\in V}$ (the additive group $(V,+)$) on a set $A$ , but (b) there must be *only one orbit* (i.e. the action must be transitive and (c) faithful. These structures, very important in mathematics, are called principal homogeneous space or torsors and can be thought as "the group (here $V,+$) without priviledged origin or unit"

Comment: Are you looking for examples or are you looking for a name?

Comment: For any action whatsoever of a group $G$ on a set $X$, the quotient group $G/K$ acts faithfully on $X$, where $K$ is the kernel of the action. So your extra condition does not result in any restrictions in the types of space that you get.

Comment: @DerekHolt I’m reading the question as “are there any topological connections between all faithfully homogeneous spaces for a given group?” in which case I feel like there ought to be some restrictions. The question may very well be, however, “what spaces are faithfully homogeneous spaces for *some* group,” in which case I agree with your comment.

Comment: @SantanaAfton, I know that in an homogeneous space is needed only that $G$ acts transitively. Yes, *question is what you write what spaces are faithfully homogeneous spaces for some group?* I know that an affine space is a group action on a set, specifically a vector space acting on a set faithfully and transitively, so I search for a name for this algebraic structure *between* affine space and vector space. Exist a name or a way to build algebraically this space?

Comment: @k.stm  I know that an affine space is a group action on a set, specifically a vector space acting on a set faithfully and transitively, so I search for a name for this algebraic structure *between* affine space and vector space. Exist a name or a way to build algebraically this space? I find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2680355/692045) something

Comment: Another example I find here, but I can't figure out for a name or for a construction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369932/g-fin-ab-group-acts-faithfully-transitively-on-x-then-x-g)